# C# Interops error running MS ACCESS macros

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop

I developed a command line app in C# that runs some macros in MS ACCESS but I am getting the following error in the production environment:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A09B6): You can´t carry out this action at the present time.
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.DoCmd.RunMacro(Object MacroName, Object RepeatCount, Object RepeatExpression)
```

When I run the application again it works fine.

This is the code:

```
public void RunMacros()
{            
    Application access = null;
    _runningMacros = true;
    CloseMessageBox("Microsoft Access");    // Thread to close MsgBoxes 
    try
    {       
        access = new Application();
        access.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;

        var databases = MdbSettings.Config.Databases;
        for (var mdbIndex = 0; mdbIndex < databases.Count; mdbIndex++)
        {
            if (databases[mdbIndex].Type == ReportType)
            {
                var mdbFile = databases[mdbIndex].File;
                if (mdbFile.StartsWith("OcnTs*", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    mdbFile = mdbFile.Replace("*", Settings.DateReplaceName);
                }
                var mdbFullPath = GetFileFullPath(mdbFile, MdbPath);
                access.OpenCurrentDatabase(mdbFullPath, Settings.IsDbExclusive);
                for (var macrosIndex = 0; macrosIndex < databases[mdbIndex].Macros.Count; macrosIndex++)
                {                            
                    var macro = databases[mdbIndex].Macros[macrosIndex].Name;
                    var message = string.Format("{0}, macro: {1}", Path.GetFileName(mdbFullPath), macro);
                    Log.Write(message);                            
                    access.DoCmd.RunMacro(macro);   
                }
                access.CloseCurrentDatabase();
            }
        }
        _runningMacros = false;     
        access.Quit(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(access);
        access = null;
    }            
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(ex.ToString());
        try
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(access);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Write("Error realeasing Access application: " + e.ToString(), Log.Severity.Warning);
        }
        throw;
    }         
}
```

Can someone help me to fix the error?

EDITED:
- The error only occurs in production environment
- The production environment has installed MS Access 2010
- The development environment has installed MS Access 2016
- Every macro run between 6 and 20 queries
- The error does not always occur in the same macro

Comment: If you're using interop to run macros that run queries, I strongly suggest cutting out the middle man, and just using interop to run queries (or better yet: don't use interop at all and run queries using the DAO database engine). If a macro encounters an error while running a query (missing parameter, unexpected null value) you can't catch that, and you will get unexpected errors like you're currently getting.

Comment: I agree with @Erik completely. But as to your added information: It's always a very bad idea to develop an Office interop solution against a newer version of the application. Always use the *oldest* version you expect to support. Generally, backwards compatibility is maintained as far as possible. The other way around, however, is not.

Comment: Due to some internal restrictions, I must call the macros instead of executing the queries directly